# advance php crawler,website with backend

Tags: php, web, web-crawler, aggregate, aggregation

my idea is,
create a website which aggregate content from other sources and display it in a page ,

say,
i have list of 10,15 websites which deals with entertainment news
i have to crawl the websites ,then save the data into database,output the contents on a web page sorted by date/time,
have to crawl heading,full content or 10,15 lines,images and then a link to the original source.
the site must be updated every 5,10 minutes.
in every update, check for new articles and display it with heading,text,image,original source link in a web page with infinite scroll.
well my experience is with php.
any php frameworks,services,classes to start on?
any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of crawling the pages and screen scraping, could you gather the same information by consuming the RSS feeds from the sites?  You should avoid screen scraping if at all possible.

If you have to scrape, try using a DOM parser, instead of a regex.
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: i tried RSS  aggregation.
the problem is 10 out of 15 RSS feed doesn't have images in it i need to parse posts with image,heading,description

Comment: I have updaed my answer to include a DOM parser instead of using a regex, to gather data from a webpage.

Comment: since i have to scrap 20,25 web pages at a time and have to save it in db, how can i achieve this by simple html dom ?